# Получить объекты, которые связанны с категорией Django

Tags: django, django-cms, django-filter

Необходимо получить объекты, которые связаны с определенной категорией, как прописать фильтр?

```
#views.py

class CategoryTemplate(ListView):
template_name = 'category.html'
model = models.State

def get_queryset(self):
    self.model = get_object_or_404(models.State, category=self.args[0])
    return models.State.objects.filter(category=self.model)

# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Категория')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

class State(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название статьи')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Выберите категорию')
    image_main = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Изображение', default="none.png", upload_to="state")
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Дата и время")
    light = "Легкий"
    middle = "Средний"
    difficult = "Сложный"
    RAITING_DIFFICULT_CHOICES = (
        (light, "Легкий"),
        (middle, "Средний"),
        (difficult, "Сложный")
    )
   raiting_difficult = models.CharField(max_length=30, 
   choices=RAITING_DIFFICULT_CHOICES, default=light, verbose_name='Уровень 
сложности')`
```

Ошибка

```
    self.model = get_object_or_404(models.State, category=self.args[0])
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
    [10/Oct/2017 11:53:06] "GET /category&id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 80178
```

Answer (score 0):

Побробуй это:

```
state = State.category_set.all().filter(category_title=категория)
```